# Keyword match type with mcf:adwordsKeywordPath

Tags: google-analytics

I use GA to download multi channel funnel report data.

Unfortunately it seems that when I put "mcf:adwordsKeywordPath" in dimensions I get the adword keywords paths, but without the match type. In Google Analytics I see that match type is shown for the keywords in mcf report.

Any idea how to get keyword path with match type?

added on 9/10/17:

I'm on developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/…. When I request mcf:adwordsKeywordPath I get the adwords keywords, but without their match type (eg broad, exact, phrase). I would have mcf:adwordsKeywordPath with keywords together with their match type; eg [pippo] / "pippo" / pluto and so on, and not only pippo / pluto without their match type. 
Or at least have a new dimension mcf:adwordsKeywordMatchTypePath.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: no news on this issue? tnx